# Go API field selection

Tags: api, go

We have a service that has a bunch of APIs defined. These APIs are consumed by various other services. My question is, is there any good patterns defined around field selection. By that I mean, our customers can provide the list of fields they want and we will query our DB based on that and return a specific required fields.

To clarify further, lets say we have a table

```
type users struct {
field1
field2
field3
field4
field5FromAnotherTable
}
```

And with a single API, we want our customers to be able to ask for specific fields from this struct and we should return only those fields. (To avoid over burdening DB and reduce network bandwidth.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What problems have you run into? Can you show your code?

Comment: Maybe you can give [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) a try.